# How do I add 2 same size imagicons into one jlabel and combine them soone is on top of another?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel, imageicon

does anyone know how to do this?
the imageicons are same demension but have transparency on one so that you can see the background icon.

---

```
 tiles[w][h] = new JLabel();
             if(tiles[10][15] == tiles[w][h]){
                 icon2 = new ImageIcon(Map.tileGrid[8][11]);
                 icon = new ImageIcon(Map.map[w][h]);
                 top.setIcon(icon2);
                 bottom.setIcon(icon);
                 top.setBounds(2, 0, 30, 30);
                 bottom.setBounds(0, 0, 30, 30);
                 resources.add(top, new Integer(1));
                 resources.add(bottom, new Integer(2));
                 tiles[w][h].add(resources);
             }
```

Something like this, and because I haven't implemented a layout manager is that the reason why it doesn't show on my map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a new ImageIcon from the combination:

```
// create the new image, canvas size is the max. of both image sizes (a and b are ImageIcons)
int w = a.getIconWidth();
int h = a.getIconHeight();
BufferedImage combined = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

// paint both images, preserving the alpha channels
Graphics g = combined.getGraphics();
g.drawImage(a.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
g.drawImage(b.getImage(), 0, 0, null);
ImageIcon result = new ImageIcon(combined);
```

You would then use `result` as the label's icon

Answer (score 1):

1. you can use [JLayer (Java7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) based on [JXLayer (Java6)](http://java.net/projects/jxlayer/)
2. you can use [OverlayLayout](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1401__OverlayLayout.htm)
3. use [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) (maybe not good way, but bunch of examples is based on)
4. `JLabel` haven't implemented any `LayoutManager`(in compare with `JFrame` or `JPanel`), you have to add proper `LayoutManager`

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to JLayer - did not know it existed!. OTOH, I think it's overkill for this problem, as positioning the icon overlay would require precise location of the icon, and that could prove fragile depending on look&feel

Comment: code at the bottom, and because I haven't implemented a layout manager is that the reason why it doesn't show on my map?